# Why do I get Unable to Open Database file?

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I am a beginner in iOS development and I want to develop a database in my application. However, When I try to create the database it says **unable to open database file**.

[image]

For clarification (https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md)

[image]

My code for the db development is as follow

```
static func DB(){

        do {
            let db = try Connection("db.sqlite3")
            let users = Table("users")
            let id = Expression<Int64>("id")
            let name = Expression<String?>("name")
            let email = Expression<String>("email")

            try db.run(users.create { t in
                t.column(id, primaryKey: true)
                t.column(name)
                t.column(email, unique: true)
                })

        } catch {
            print("Dim background error")
        }
}
```

I trigger this method from app delegate file

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        AppCommon.DB()

        return true
    }
```

How to fix this issue? Please help me out, I really need your help..!

Comment: What is `Connection`? Show how it attempts to open the database file.

Comment: @rmaddy - Actually it's been told that, if the connection won't find the file. It will attempt to create the file. Problem is it does not create it.

Comment: You need to specify the full path to the file, not just the filename.

Comment: @rmaddy - How do I mention the full path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On iOS, you can't create files where you want. A correct place (among others) is in the *documents directory*.

Quoting the documentation of the library you are using https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#connecting-to-a-database:

> On iOS, you can create a writable database in your app’s Documents directory.
>
> ```
> let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
>    .DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true
> ).first!
>
> let db = try Connection("\(path)/db.sqlite3")
> ```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 5**

Path of Documents directory is now an array of strings

```
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                .documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
let db = try Connection("\(path.first ?? "")/db.sqlite3")
```