# Cannot create sqlite file with SQLite.swift "cannot open file at line..."

Tags: swift, sqlite, sqlite.swift

I'm attempting to create a sqlite DB file within my iOS project. I'm using the code as [documented](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#read-write-databases) for R/W

```swift
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
    .documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true
).first!

let db = try Connection("\(path)/db.sqlite3")
```

but I end up with a `cannot open file at line 45340 of [d24547a13b]`.

The closest resource I've found is [Why do I get Unable to Open Database file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34702312/why-do-i-get-unable-to-open-database-file) but the code there seems to be the same as what I have.

edit: More logs

```
[logging-persist] os_unix.c:45340: (0) open
- Undefined error: 0
```

Comment: No more in the error message than that?

Comment: Added the last few lines!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DB file needs to be created under the `documents` directory. See Brando Flores' answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70514807/346676

```
do {
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let dbFile = "\(path.first ?? "")/db.sqlite3"
    print(dbFile)   // show full file path
    db = try Connection(dbFile)
}
catch {
    print(error)
}
```